# PHP String Operators add variable

Tags: php, string, variables, operators, addition

I have asigned variable like:

```
$name = "sometext";
```

And i stuck with this code line:

```
$output .= '<a href="'. home_url() .'"><img src="'. $t_custom_logo .'" border="0" class="png" alt="'. get_bloginfo('name') .'" /></a>';
```

How can i  echo or some how to make it apear $name value  after

```
$output .= '<a href="'. home_url() .
```

So the main thing in result could look like this:

```
<a href="www.somelink.com/sometext"> ....
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do what you've been doing the whole time, concatenation:

```
$output .= '<a href="'. home_url() . '/'. $name'"><img src="'. $t_custom_logo .'" border="0" class="png" alt="'. get_bloginfo('name') .'" /></a>';
```

Comment: Done that, but it doesnt show a thing :/ Could it be becouse of functions or smthn ? Maybe should add global ?

Comment: This code should work. Maybe you should show us more code which may be helpful.

Comment: Everithing works now, The code line is absolutely corect :) i still don't get why it couldn't show my variable outside of functions so i put the whole thing $name = "sometext"; inside the function and it showed up :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add it like the other functions' results / strings using the `.` operator.

```
$output .= '<a href="'. home_url() . $name . '"><img src="'. $t_custom_logo .'" border="0" class="png" alt="'. get_bloginfo('name') .'" /></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$output .= '<a href="'. home_url() . $name .'">
```

If home_url() does not have the / at the end then you will need to put this in manually

```
$output .= '<a href=~'. home_url() . '/' . $name .'">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.` operator is the string concatenation operator in PHP. It doesn't need to be followed by or preceded by quotes. `$output .= '<a href="'. home_url() . $name`... will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

or

```
$output .= '<a href="'. home_url() . '/' . $name . '"><img src="'. $t_custom_logo .'" border="0" class="png" alt="'. get_bloginfo('name') .'" /></a>';
```

if you also need to add the "/" too

Answer (score 0):

You can use this following tutorial to get domain name [get domain name](http://corpocrat.com/2009/02/28/php-how-to-get-domain-hostname-from-url/) and then append it witn your `$name` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use sprintf will make your code more readable.

```
$output .= sprintf( 
    '<a href="%s"><img src="%s" border="0" class="png" alt="%s" /></a>',
    home_url().'/'.$name,
    $t_custom_logo,
    get_bloginfo('name')
);
```